# Update values correctly using if ternary

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator, ternary

I am trying to update values of an array givinga certain condition, using this code:

```
a=[np.inf, 2, 3]

for i in range(0,10):
    a[0] = 100 if a[0] == np.inf else a.append(1)
    print(a)
```

The firs iteration works perfectly fine, and changes the infinity values per 100. However, in the subsequent iterations it adds the number 1, but change the first values of the array by `None`.

```
[100, 2, 3] 
[None, 2, 3, 1] 
[None, 2, 3, 1, 1] 
...
[None, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `.append()` returns None -- it does not return the appended value.

Comment: What @JohnGordon said. You are assigning the `None` value to `a[0]` and appending the 1 to the *new* `a`

Comment: Is it because I can not be associated the `.append()` method with any variable? so for instance I can not do `x=a.append(1)`

Comment: You can do that, but `x` will always be None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
a[0] = 100 if a[0] == np.inf else a.append(1)
```

can be written as

```
if a[0] == np.inf:
    a[0] = 100
else:
    a[0] = a.append(1)
```

I'm sure you can see the problem there. The ternary if selects a value to use, you can't use it in the way you're attempting.

I suspect you were reading it as

```
(a[0] = 100) if a[0] == np.inf else a.append(1)
```

when it's actually

```
a[0] = (100 if a[0] == np.inf else a.append(1))
```

Comment: I was reading the ternary as you guessed. But still, in the second iteration, `a[0]` is not infinity so it should append the number 1, isn't it?

Comment: Correct, you append `1` to the array if `a[0] == np.inf` evaluates to `false`, which it will if `a[0]` is `100` as it will be on the second iteration or `None` as it is on all iterations after that.